# Mimic alternate row in html

Tags: html, css, rows, alternate

I have a website with a list of `<div>`s being displayed. The `<div>`s have alternate background-color based on `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)`. No problem at all with that.

What I need is a way to make the alternate background-color even after the last div. Sort of how Mac OS Finder Window works (is the inspiration of the client).

How to do that? Is there any way other than the clunky "create empty divs"?

image of mac folder in list view:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a complete code example showing what you've tried? I don't understand the "after the last div" part of your question.

Comment: Why not just have a repeating background on the element that contains all your div?

Comment: @j08691 Im guessing he wants the alternating rows to continue even if there isn't any content.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu nailed it. That's what I want. I didn't think about the background image. That could be it.
Either way, isn't it possible with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a background image or background gradient to get the repeating pattern in the container element.

The disadvantage would be if the alternating divs were of varying heights.

Example ([jSFiddle for visual](http://jsfiddle.net/5w3tn25v/1/)):

```
#container{
   background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, 
    lightgray,
    lightgray 10px,
    white 10px,
    white 20px
  );
}
```

Try experimenting with different units (i.e. EMs instead of pixels) and you should be able to achieve something close to the Finder background. Note, you likely will need to use vendor prefixes for browser compatibility.

Comment: the divs are of fixed heights. I'm new to HTML / CSS, so let me just clarify: Will the background be used in the whole page or just after the last row? Thinking of it with this perspective, I think a background for the whole page would do...

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, isn't it possible to do it with CSS? A CSS-background? Sorry if I am too layman.

Comment: You could just as easily use a CSS `background-image` with the CSS property `background-repeat: repeat;`. Programmatically might offer future flexibility in case you change your font size or something, that way you don't have to recreate the background image.

Comment: Perfect @quantastical! Noob related question: is it possible to set the height to the browser size? Like, not 800px, but 100% of window height.

Comment: 100% height is a bit more complicated but, yes, it is possible. The easy way would be to use a unit called `vh` meaning "viewport height", but compatibility, from what I recall, is not great. Therefore, if you want to use percent units, you'll need to do some stuff to ensure the `body` and `html` elements are `height: 100%;` and account for any margins, padding, etc. The question about 100% height has been asked many times, so you should be able to find code examples simply by searching for "css 100% height" (or something similar) in Stack Overflow or Google.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to do this with CSS and your list html is wrapped in  tags you could assign a background or background-color property in a class to that  tag. ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/919fs9mz/)).

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: -40px;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: gray;
    margin-left: -40px;
}
.list {
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    background: gray;
}
```

If you're list is not wrapped in UL tags then you may want to reconsider how you've got your html structured.

Comment: The OP has already stated they're using `:nth-child(even/odd)` what they want to do is continue this pattern even after the list has finished - please read the question again.

Comment: I included the nth-child(even/odd) code to help frame out the answer. If you indeed read my answer you saw that the point was to place the alternate background color in the list parent. If you look at the fiddle I included it displays what was asked. Being a new contributor to this site and not having enough rep to comment on the question before answering, I took a shot at actually trying to help them get a working answer based on the information given. Thank you for assuming I blindly posted an answer though.

Comment: I didn't assume anything, and I don't think there's any need for the sarcasm. If you look at the OP's screenshot, you can clearly see the even/odd pattern continues way after the list is finished. I'm sorry if you don't like my comment, it was not a personal attack, but it does not answer the question correctly.

Comment: I thank you for the help, but, indeed, the fiddle doesn't make the "full alternating row". The answer from @quantastical solved exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help, even though.

Comment: it's weird but I can only see the very top of your screenshot.